# large negative number multiplied by -1 gives output negative c++

Tags: c++, multiplication

Why is the output of this program -2147483648?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long a=-2147483648;
    a=a*-1;
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

It should be 2147483648 because it is in range of `long long`. Why the sign is not changing? I have even tried `abs()` function but the result is the same.

Also more surprising is that this program outputs 2147483648:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long a=-2147483648;
    a=a*-1;
    a=a*-1;
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

The second time, multiplying by -1 worked. If it matters, I'm using C++ 4.8.1.

Comment: What is `long long` on your system? Are you 100% sure that you did not use `long` in the first version?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [Just tried with GCC/g++](http://ideone.com/HJjKtB). `sizeof(long long)` is 8, yet the output is negative. I tried the exact same code on my Mac with `clang++`, and it gave the expected (positive) result.

Comment: Is the compiler performing the multiplication in the context of `int`?

Comment: I have ran it on ideone too so long long is 8 bits and its g++ 4.8.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable `-Wall` and you'll see the answer.

```
foo.C:5: warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90
```

Use `-2147483648LL` in place of your constant.

Answer (score 4):

Add 'll' to the end of your declaration:

```
long long a=-2147483648ll;
```

I checked this on IDEONE and saw the problem and verified the fix. The problem is that your constant value exceeds that for a default int so you have to type it (as long long) to get the constant you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to qualify the constant as: `-2147483648LL` - C++11 should promote it to `long long` automatically. Then again, `long long` isn't standard in C++03.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the minimum negative value is -2147483648 however the maximum positive value is 2147483647. Notice the last digit in the both numbers.:) So value 2147483648 can not be represented in your long long type but could be represented in unsigned long long type.
The same problem for example exists with function abs().

Comment: `long long` is a 64 bit type it would seem so this is not the case

Comment: But -2147483648 to 2147483647 is range for int(4 bit) but I am using long long which is 8 bit and has a huge range

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, the problem is the type of the literal, not the type of the variable it is stored to.

Answer (score 0):

When I compile this with g++ 4.8.1, it warns:

```
warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90
```

which seems to indicate that the type you use is unsigned. You can confirm this by outputting the value of `a` before the multiplication. When compiling with `-std=c++11` the used type is signed, and it behaves as you expected.